# How to use the Osepp proximity module with arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno, proximity

I have recently purchased an [Osepp proximity module](https://www.osepp.com/electronic-modules/sensor-modules/75-ir-proximity-sensor-module) at Radio Shack and am attempting to use it with my Arduino Uno. How should I connect it to the 
Arduino, and what library do I use?

Comment: What's an "Osepp proximity module"?  Links please.

Comment: https://www.osepp.com/electronic-modules/sensor-modules/75-ir-proximity-sensor-module

Comment: Well, it states that it uses a "GP2Y0D805Z0F", so googling for that plus Arduino gives plenty of results, including an Adafuit one, and they are notoriously good with their documentation and example code, so you should check that out first.

Comment: That's how to use the "GP2Y0D805Z0F". I'm trying to connect the Osepp board to the arduino, not the raw distance sensor.

Comment: With wires. Connect the correct pins on the board (I2C pins...) to the Arduino's I2C pins. The pins are shown in the schematic linked from that page.

Comment: Forgive me for being completely new to Arduino, but I have no idea how to follow that diagram.

Comment: Looking over your question, @Majenko's answer and the comments - you already have everything you need except for some work on your part.  If you are still lost - I would suggest to put everything you have bought aside, find a posting where someone has done the work, buy exactly the same items and copy the posting step by step.  [Like this posting which uses similar parts](https://www.makerguides.com/sharp-gp2y0a21yk0f-ir-distance-sensor-arduino-tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

> How should I connect it to the Arduino

Refer to the schematic in the page you link to. That shows you which pin is which.  It's I2C, so there's just 2 data pins, power, and ground.

> and what library do I use?

The Osepp board is a GP2Y0D805Z0F connected to a PCA9534 IO expander. There is a library [here](https://github.com/alotaiba/PCA9534).

Comment: I have no idea which pins on the arduino itself besides maybe the 5v and gnd. Is the data cable analog or digital? Is the clock cable even necessary? If so, what pins will work with it?

Comment: Look at the pretty pictures of the board and the arduino and match the names. Learn what I2C is. Understanding schematics is absolutely fundamental to working with electronics.